# Finding Visual C++ tools' include folder location for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, visual-studio-2017

In VS2017 location of Visual C++ Tools [has new installation model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/06/finding-the-visual-c-compiler-tools-in-visual-studio-2017/)

Now it is located somwhere like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\**Enterprise**\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.**11.25203**. 
Or it can be for example C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\**Community**\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.**10.25017**. 
So full path depends on VS2017 **edition** and **build number**.

There is a macro **$(VCInstallDir)** which points to **..\VC** folder. But I need to know full path including part which depends on VS2017 **build number**. I need this to find Visual C++ tools' include folder.

So can I determine this path without calling VS2017 Command Prompt (VCVARSALL.BAT) or PowerShell script etc.? Is thete some VS macro that I can simply put into **VC++ Directory\Additional Directories** property of my project?

Comment: Why do you change the *default* include path? If you leave it as is, and only use the *additional include path*, you will never have such issues.

Comment: I'm changing _additional include path_, but I'm not building solution via VS2017 - I'm calling NMAKE (which calls MSBUILD for solution inside).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out MSBuild variable `$(VCToolsInstallDir)`, it should do the job for you. It is available in VS2017 C++ projects and its value is set to something like

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\
```

(depending on your tools version). Alternatively you can use `$(VCInstallDir)` and `$(VCToolsVersion)` to construct the path, but `$(VCToolsInstallDir)` should be more reliable.

P.S. Please note these variables only work in VS 2017 and *are not available in previous versions* of Visual Studio.

Comment: It looks like `$(VCToolsInstallDir)` is not defined in a C# project using Visual Studio 2019. I would like to use `editbin.exe`.